# SVN : Redirect cycle detected for URL

Tags: apache, svn

I know this has been asked many time and i have seen that questions's answer too but dont know what i am missing. it would be great if you guys can look into it

successfully installed svn - from this tutorial

```
 tecadmin.net/setup-subversion-server-on-centos/
```

my **httpd.conf** file

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

Alias /svn /var/www/svn

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion User Authentication "
   AuthUserFile /etc/svn-users
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

also i created svn in var/ folder and it was giving that same error ( Redirect cycle detected for URL)  and still when i created in var/www/ it is also giving the same error.

Comment: Anyone can answer this question?I got the same problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error message but for a different (unknown) reason.

What I have seen is that you cannot have svn as a subdirectory of your normal web server DocumentRoot. Your /var/www/svn looks as if it might be in this category if your Apache is configured to serve from /var/www

But my svn is in /var/lib/svn, well away from /var/www/html, and I'm still getting this error message, as are lots of other people.

Comment: I had this problem as having followed the same tutorial as everyone else (presumably), I had /home/svn and the repos were inside that (/home/svn/client1, /home/svn/client2, etc). The error is caused when you put ````Alias /svn <anything>````. I moved the index.php (which lists summaries) to /var/www/svn and removed the directive. Now everything works fine.